# Creating new columns to count shots missed/ shots taken by date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create two additional columns to my current df. One column is to register shots made daily and the other one would be to show how many shots where attempted daily as well.

I have tried:

```
df.groupby("Date")['ShotMade','ShotTaken'].count()
```

But I am not getting the output wanted. Thanks in advance!

This is my current data frame:

```
     Date  ShotMade  ShotTaken
4/20/2020         0          1
4/20/2020         0          1
4/20/2020         1          1
4/20/2020         1          1
4/21/2020         1          1
4/21/2020         1          1
4/21/2020         1          1
4/22/2020         1          1
4/22/2020         1          1
4/22/2020         0          1
4/22/2020         0          1
4/22/2020         0          1
```

Desired output:

```
     Date  ShotMade  ShotTaken
4/20/2020         2          4
4/21/2020         3          3
4/22/2020         2          5
```

Comment: Try df.groupby('Date').sum()

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby_sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) instead of [`groupby_count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) to sum values and not count items for each group. Use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` for selecting columns else Pandas will raise a `FutureWarning`:

```
out = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False)[['ShotMade', 'ShotTaken']].sum()
print(out)

# Output
     Date  ShotMade  ShotTaken
4/20/2020         2          4
4/21/2020         3          3
4/22/2020         2          5
```